# Select and Option other than the default value

Tags: javascript

How would i go about alerting the user after they click the submit button to choose an option from the select boxes other than the default value using javascript here's my code

```
<select id = "Sel">
    <option value ="Song1">default value<br>
    <option value ="Song2">Break on through<br>
    <option value ="Song3">Time<br>
    <option value ="Song4">Money<br>
    <option value="Song5">Saucerful of Secrets
</select><br><br>
```

heres my javascript code im not sure where to start, but this doesnt run

```
if(document.getElementByID("Sel").value = "default value")
{
    alert("Pick another option besides default value");
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does the javascript you have look like so far?

Comment: Your markup is not correct. The `<option>` tag is not closed. And Show us what you have tried and where you are having issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, you markup is not correct.. correct it as

```
<select id = "Sel">
    <option value ="Song1">default value</option>
    <option value ="Song2">Break on through</option>
    <option value ="Song3">Time</option>
    <option value ="Song4">Money</option>
    <option value="Song5">Saucerful of Secrets</option>
</select><br><br>
```

then on form submit check as

```
if(document.getElementById('Sel').value=="Song1")
    return false;
```

OR

```
if(document.getElementById('Sel').selectedIndex ==0)
    return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is wrong in the first place.. Need to close the **opening options tag**

In the change event check the value ... 
If `value is Song1`  then alert to the user

**HTML**

```
<select id = "Sel">
    <option value ="Song1">default value</option>
    <option value ="Song2">Break on through</option>
    <option value ="Song3">Time</option>
    <option value ="Song4">Money</option>
    <option value="Song5">Saucerful of Secrets</option>
</select>​
```

**Javascript**

```
var elem = document.getElementById('submit');

elem.addEventListener('click', function(){
   var selectElem = document.getElementById('Sel');
   var val = selectElem.value;
    if(val == 'Song1'){
        alert('Select an option!!');
        return false;
    }        
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/9Pem8/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#Sel').change(function() {
                    if($(this).val()=="Song1"){
                        alert('bad');
                    }else{
                        alert('good');
                    }
                });
                $('#button-test').click(function() {
                    var bob = $('#Sel').val();
                    if (bob=='Song1'){
                        alert('bad');
                    }else{
                        alert('good');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>

<select id = "Sel">
    <option value ="Song1">default value</option>
    <option value ="Song2">Break on through</option>
    <option value ="Song3">Time</option>
    <option value ="Song4">Money</option>
    <option value="Song5">Saucerful of Secrets</option>
</select><br>
<br>
<button id="button-test">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#Sel").live('click', function (event) {
        var myval=$(this).val;
        alert(myval);
        });
    </script>   
    <select id = "Sel">
            <option name="opSel" value ="Song1">default value</option>
            <option name="opSel" value ="Song2">Break on through</option>
            <option name="opSel" value ="Song3">Time</option>
            <option name="opSel" value ="Song4">Money</option>
            <option name="opSel" value="Song5">Saucerful of Secrets</option>
        </select>
```